# VB.Net compiled for 32 bit running on 64 bit machine using SQLite

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, 64-bit, 32-bit

Here's the situation - I have a vb.net exe compiled for X86 machines using 2 dll's... Because one of the dll's was only provided in 32 bit, and I didn't want to have to deal with 32/64 versions, I forced 32 bit in compile options and everything was fine. Now I have a 64 bit workstation that is throwing an error about the sqlite.dll (error #1 below)... after reading around I am starting to understand a lot of people are having this issue. I tried replacing the dll on the client machine with the 64 bit version of sqlite and that didn't work (error #2). I read somewhere that the 64 bit version requires VC 2010 redistro, but that didn't work. I can't compile this app as a 64 bit because of the other dll is 32 bit. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Error #1** - System.InvalidOperationException: No connection associated with this command

**Error #2** - System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.79.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
File name: 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.79.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'

Comment: One last note... I know this is not a permissions thing because I can manually edit the sqlite file with SQLite Database Browser under the same user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure that you've compiled your application under x86, not AnyCPU? When dealing with dlls like SQLLite that are compiled for x86, your process must be running in x86 mode.

Comment: Absolutely sure. If I even fiddle with this setting (change it to 64 or any) my other dll breaks the program right away.

Comment: You're deploying the x86 version of the SQLLite dll with your app, correct? Is it possible that the x64 version of SQLLite is registered in the GAC and somehow getting picked up from there? .NET will probe the GAC for assemblies before your local bin directory.

Comment: For sh*%# and giggles, try having your app load the SQLLite assembly manually on startup using Assembly.LoadFrom

Comment: I am fairly confident the program is picking up the x86 SQLite version, but is there some way I can be certain after the program is running which version of the dll it loaded? Also, if I compile the app as X86, wouldn't it only work with 32bit dll's? The client machine is 64bit and I know for sure which version of the dll it is loading because this computer doesn't have any other SQLite dll's other than the one I provide.

Comment: The problem is happening when the AppDomain actually loads the assembly, so you can't see it at runtime within the context of your program itself. You can check the Fusion log viewer to see and verify where your SQLLite dll is being loaded from.

Comment: I figured it out, your suggestion lead me down the right path. The first error described above was correct, I was not connecting to the db because I had the connection in a try catch that was failing before it got here on some machines. Also, I had the wrong dll in various places (bin folder, etc.). Once I cleaned this up my 32 bit program worked great on all 64 bit machines. Thank you.